# process Dialog not Showing immediately in List View

Tags: android

Hi I am new to Android and trying to put process dialog on List View like this way.

```
    lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v,int position, long id) {
            Log.v("data1","Before Dialog");
            pd = ProgressDialog.show(DataDiaryDateAndTime.this.getParent(), "",
                    "Please Wait....", true, true);
            Log.v("data1","After Dialog");
            MyThreadNew myThread = new MyThreadNew(position);
            myThread.start();
        }
    });
```

but I found that the process dialog starting very late but both messages comes immediately
My Activity is child Activity of other Activity.

please give me appropriate solution
Thanks.

Comment: may be it is taking some time in updating the ui thread with progress dialog,since it has a list view, just a guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you testing this in emulator? emulator is slower(quite slow especially in debug mode).
how does it behaves in the actual device?